# What is the simplest way to build your own .deb package?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, deb

Having used Ubuntu for several years now, I've assembled a short list of scripts and packages that I always install on my computers.  I would like to pack them up into a .deb to make it easier to get set up on a fresh OS installation.  I'm imagining, for instance, one package that would install all of my custom BASH scripts that I've made for common tasks, and another one that would depend on other packages (like `w64codecs`) that I always install but forget that I need to until I go to do something and it's not there.

It doesn't even have to be by-the-book; I'm not looking to deploy these publicly.  I'm just looking to roll up all these tasks into one `sudo dpkg --install`.

To quantify "simple" or "easy," I mean to say that I'm looking for the method with the fewest steps requiring the least technical knowledge and, most importantly, taking the least time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

checkinstall - you'd need to know how to do the usual ./configure, make ,make install way of installing, then just replace make install with checkinstall (./configure , make , sudo checkinstall) . The package for checkinstall is in ubuntu

if its just scripts, just save it as a .sh file.

Comment: I was imagining a situation where I'd be packing something that I didn't compile -- just installing a bunch of files to various locations in the computer and depending on other packages.  Checkinstall does seem to be the best package-based solution that I've found... but as I started looking at how I would do what I wanted to do in checkinstall, I'm finding that the easiest way to do what I want is actually just to make a huge BASH script with a bunch of `echo >` and `echo >>` and `apt-get -y install`.

So you're right on both counts!